# Counting slides shift in javascript object

Tags: javascript, algorithm, array

Adding Dynamic Slides to a slider used by a client shifts its index, need to account for that so i wrote this simple code, but i think it's pretty lame, is there any way to improve it and accomplish the same output?

```js
var slides = {
  1: {
    content: "",
    group: 1
  },
  2: {
    group: 1
  },
  3: {
    content: "",
    group: 1
  },
  4: {
    content: "",
    group: 2
  },
  5: {
    content: "",
    group: 3
  },
  6: {
    content: "",
    group: 3
  },
  7: {
    content: "",
    group: 3
  },
  8: {
    content: "",
    group: 4
  },
  9: {
    content: "",
    group: 4
  },
  10: {
    content: "",
    group: 4
  },
  11: {
    content: "",
    group: 5
  },
  12: {
    content: "",
    group: 5
  }
};

var shiftCount = [],
  shiftCounter = 0,
  lastgroup, lastcount;
for (var slideIndex in slides) {
  var group = parseInt(slides[slideIndex].group, 10);
  if (group === 1) { //no shift caused by 1st group
    shiftCount.push(0);
  } else {
    if (group !== lastgroup) { //stay on current group.
      lastcount = shiftCount.length;
      lastgroup = group;
      shiftCount.push(shiftCount.length);
    } else { //fill rest of array with repeated count and match length.
      shiftCount.push(lastcount);
    }
  }
}
console.log(shiftCount);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You never use the `shiftcounter` variable, so feel free to remove it.

You don't care about the keys in the object you're iterating over, you only care about the objects at each key - so, it would be more appropriate to iterate just over the values, rather than the keys. Use `Object.values` instead of `for..in`.

The `.group` property is already an integer in the dataset, so there's no need to call `parseInt` with it. Since you want to extract the `group` property into a variable named `group`, you can do this more concisely with destructuring.

Rather than hard-coding the action to take when the group is 1 (the first), you can initialize `lastGroup` to `1` so that the `//fill rest of array with repeated count and match length` section will take care of the logic you need - it'll be more DRY.

```
const shiftCount = [];
let lastgroup = 1, // initial group
  lastcount = 0; // initial count
for (const { group } of Object.values(slides)) {
  if (group !== lastgroup) {
    lastcount = shiftCount.length;
    lastgroup = group;
    shiftCount.push(lastcount);
  } else { //fill rest of array with repeated count and match length.
    shiftCount.push(lastcount);
  }
}
```

```js
const slides = {
  1: {
    content: "",
    group: 1
  },
  2: {
    group: 1
  },
  3: {
    content: "",
    group: 1
  },
  4: {
    content: "",
    group: 2
  },
  5: {
    content: "",
    group: 3
  },
  6: {
    content: "",
    group: 3
  },
  7: {
    content: "",
    group: 3
  },
  8: {
    content: "",
    group: 4
  },
  9: {
    content: "",
    group: 4
  },
  10: {
    content: "",
    group: 4
  },
  11: {
    content: "",
    group: 5
  },
  12: {
    content: "",
    group: 5
  }
};

const shiftCount = [];
let lastgroup = 1,
  lastcount = 0;
for (const { group } of Object.values(slides)) {
  if (group !== lastgroup) {
    lastcount = shiftCount.length;
    lastgroup = group;
    shiftCount.push(lastcount);
  } else { //fill rest of array with repeated count and match length.
    shiftCount.push(lastcount);
  }
}
console.log(shiftCount);
```